# How to add all numbers in a list using Counter?

Tags: python, list, counter

I have a list like this:

```
[1, 1, 78, 7701], [1, 2, 78, 7527], [1, 3, 78, 8825], [1, 4, 78, 8859], [1, 5, 78, 9043], [1, 6, 78, 9208], [1, 7, 78, 8084], [1, 8, 78, 7611], [1, 9, 78, 9172], [1, 10, 78, 9089], [1, 11, 78, 9210], [1, 12, 78, 9259], [1, 13, 78, 9138], [1, 14, 78, 8299], [1, 15, 78, 7771], [1, 16, 78, 9458], [1, 17, 78, 9339], [1, 18, 78, 9120], [1, 19, 78, 9226]
```

The first column is the month. I want to use `Counter` to add all the numbers in the last column (within the same month).

Comment: [1, 1, 78, 7701],
 [1, 2, 78, 7527],
 [1, 3, 78, 8825],
 [1, 4, 78, 8859],
 [1, 5, 78, 9043],
 [1, 6, 78, 9208],
 [1, 7, 78, 8084],
 [1, 8, 78, 7611],
 [1, 9, 78, 9172],
 [1, 10, 78, 9089],
 [1, 11, 78, 9210],
 [1, 12, 78, 9259],
 [1, 13, 78, 9138],
 [1, 14, 78, 8299],
 [1, 15, 78, 7771],

Comment: what is your desired output?

Comment: Please add code/data as *formatted text* in the question itself, do not post images or (especially not) links to images. Also, provide a [mcve] of what you've tried and how it failed.

Comment: I want to calculate the sum of last column for each month

Comment: Can you post your full array in your question?

Comment: S/O Review: @RickySi Can you please share some of your attempted code with the S/O community? Giving folks a starting point will help them better answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a dictionary to keep track of sums for each month:

```
arr = [[1, 1, 78, 7701], [1, 2, 78, 7527], [2, 3, 78, 8825]]

sums = {}
for a in arr:
    sums[a[0]] = sums.get(a[0], 0) + a[3]

print(sums)
```

Output:

```
{1: 15228, 2: 8825}
```

Comment: `sums[a[0]] = sums.get(a[0], 0) + a[3]` for succinctness.

Comment: Nice! Didn't know about that, thanks for the improvement, updated.

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned you want to use `Counter`, you can do it like this:

```
result = Counter()
for (month, _, _, s) in arr:
    result[month] += s
print(result)
```

Which outputs:

```
Counter({1: 165939})
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `zip` to group each column together and sum them up.

```
mylist = [  
[1, 1, 78, 7701], [1, 2, 78, 7527], 
[1, 3, 78, 8825], [1, 4, 78, 8859]]

for idx, item in enumerate(zip(*mylist)):
    if idx == 3:
        print "the summation is: ", sum(item)
```

Comment: This does not differentiate sums based on the month in the first column, which is what the user asked for.